# Websphere Application Server 9.0.0.1 - EntityManager is null every other request

Tags: jax-rs, websphere, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to run a project on WAS 9.0.0.1, that currently works fine on WAS 8.5.5.x.  The problem seems to be that entitymanager is not being injected into the DAO, but this only happens every other request.  So when doing the em.createNamedQuery in the DAO it is throwing a NullPointerException because the em is null, like I explained above the strange thing is that it is only failing like this every other request.  Any ideas?

Persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="OperationsAPI" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/operations</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.i3.operations.entities.Operation</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Resource class:

```
@Path("/operations")
@Api("Operations API")
@Stateless
public class OperationsService {

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OperationsService.class.getName());

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @EJB
    private static OperationDAO operationDAO;

    public OperationsService() {
    operationDAO = new OperationDAO();
    }

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets all operations", response = Operation.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getOperationsAll() {

    List<Operation> operations = operationDAO.getOperationsAll();

    return Response.ok().entity(operations).build();
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class OperationDAO {

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OperationDAO.class.getName());


    @PersistenceContext(unitName="OperationsAPI")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Operation> getOperationsAll() {

        logger.info("EntityManager: " + em);
        TypedQuery<Operation> query = em.createNamedQuery("Operation.findAll", Operation.class);
        return query.getResultList();

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly.  But, I'd guess in newing this up directly `operationDAO = new OperationDAO();` you are not triggering the container's injection of the **EntityManager**.    Should you be having the container inject **OperationDAO** all the time instead, instead of overwriting a static field in the no-arg constructor?

Comment: Ahh, you are correct that should not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically don't want to mix use of both the **new** operator and also dependency injection (CDI, etc.) to set the same object references in a given class.

If your dependency graph is mostly using dependency injection then dependency injection (DI) should be instantiating all the objects.  Otherwise you end up with the case that you create an object instance that DI doesn't know about, so it doesn't know to inject its dependencies into.

This is probably what's happening in your case.   Since these EJB instances are pooled, you may end up with some of your instances having been initialized correctly, and some not.

You probably want to change to just (or remove and default):

```
 public OperationsService() {}
```

I'll mention I'm not sure injecting into a **static** field  is a good idea, but I'm not really enough of an expert to suggest removing the **static** modifier from *operationDAO*.